# PyQt: Get current Qt.DockWidgetArea of QDockWidget

Tags: c++, python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

How would you find the current `Qt.DockWidgetArea` of a `QDockWidget`? I would like to be able to hide `QDockWidget`'s depending on their position respect the `QMainWindow.centralWidget()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `.dockWidgetArea(<QDockWidget>)` from your `QMainWindow` should give you what you need.

([docs](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qmainwindow.html#dockWidgetArea))